# GPO pushed printers not installed in RDS session

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, printing, rds, network-printer, print-server

We have an Remote Desktop Service environment with 3 Windows server 2012 R2 session hosts. The customer has 8 separate offices with 1 Kyocera network printer in each office.
For management purposes we installed the printers on a separate print server (also 2012 R2) with the correct type of Kyocera print drivers (v4) for each printer.

The printers are:

```
Kyocera TASKalfa 2551ci
Kyocera TASKalfa 2552ci
Kyocera TASKalfa 3050ci
```

We created a group policy to push every printer to every users because they switch offices regularly. 
Group policy Use Remote Desktop Easy Print printer driver first has been disabled.
RPC calls are possible between the RDS session hosts and the print server.

Now we see the following issue from time to time:

Let's say there are 15 users logged on to one RDS session host, 14 users can print without a problem. 1 user can't. When he tries to open Word and want to print a document he receives the error **'no printers are installed'**. Every printer has the status 'Ready'. But when this users opens Excel, every printer has the error message **'cannot connect to printer'**. Which is strange because the other lets say 15 users on that RDS session host can printer without a problem.

The issue is solved when we delete the User Profile Disk and let RDS create a new one.

From time to time i see the following error in the Operational print logs on the print server

> The print job 29 was sent through the print processor MS_XPS_PROC on printer XXX, driver Kyocera CS 2551ci v4 KX (PCL6), in the isolation mode 0 (0 - loaded in the spooler, 1 - loaded in shared sandbox, 2 - loaded in isolated sandbox). Win32 error code returned by the print processor: 0x6BE.

Also, a couple of times per hour i see the following error in the Admin print logs on the print server. I'm not sure if the document has been printed or not when this error occures.

> The document Print Document, owned by PERSON A, failed to print on
>   printer XXX. Try to print the document again, or restart the print
>   spooler.  Data type: RAW. Size of the spool file in bytes: 0. Number
>   of bytes printed: 0. Total number of pages in the document: 0. Number
>   of pages printed: 0. Client computer: RDS02. Win32 error code returned
>   by the print processor: 1726. The remote procedure call failed.

Does anyone has an solution for this problem?

Kind regards,

Gijs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by switching the print drivers from v4 to v3 drivers.

From my understanding has the user download his v4 drivers himself via Windows Update/Windows Store. The print servers only tells the user which drivers he needs.

v3 drivers are actually pushed by the print server to the user his RDS profile. The user does not need to download the drivers himself.

Now, when you're working in a locked down environment like our RDS, you do not have the rights to download the v4 driver to your profile.
So all the users had their printers pushed with the 'microsoft enhanced point and print compatibility driver' driver instead of the one we configured on the print server.

After switching all the drivers on the print server to v3, these were pushed to the users. From that point we didn't had a single print failure in our setup.

Kind regards,